# is it possible to know when user click on advertisement on youtube video?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is it possible to know when user click on advertisement on youtube video?

We used youtube api v2 in our website, and user can watch videos.

Problem : when user click on advertisement , youtube video pause automatically.

My Task is to make youtube video continuously play even if user click on advertisement,

It should only pause when user click on pause button.

is there any solution?

Comment: hmmmmm have you looked into it @hmmmmm ?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to capture the event (click) prior to the handler being fired.

If these are two separated handlers then you probably CAN do this.  Just find/remove the one handler on page load.  Or you may be able to insert a lower-level handler that just stops the event from propagating upwards.

IF the event handler that launches the ad also pauses the video, then no you can't keep the video playing while the user is in an ad.  However, you may be able to add a second handler that ALSO launches, which resumes the video.  It'll result in a hiccup, but users probably won't complain.